# логика модели Джанго

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-model

**Как правильно сделать модель для выбора?**

```
    rouse = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_R, max_length=20, default=R37)
    color = models.ChoicesText(choices=CHOICES_C, max_length=20, default=C1)
    if (color == color.C1):
        s_color = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_S, max_length=20, default=None)
    elif (color.choices == C2):
        s_color1 = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_S, max_length=20, default=None)
        s_color2 = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_S, max_length=20, default=None)
    elif (color.choices == C3):
        s_color1 = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_S, max_length=20, default=None)
        s_color2 = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_S, max_length=20, default=None)
        s_color3 = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_S, max_length=20, default=None)
```

так, к сожалению, не работает. С js не дружу. Или, при выборе колличества цвета, можно это реализовать через форму? Можно ж как-то это реализовать...

Comment: вы же ознакомились с документацией? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно хранить список s_color в одном поле

```
color = models.ChoicesText(choices=CHOICES_C, max_length=20, default=C1)
scolor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
def set_scolor(self, x):
    self.scolor = json.dumps(x)

def get_scolor(self):
    return json.loads(self.scolor)
scolor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
def set_scolor(self, x):
    self.scolor = json.dumps(x)

def get_scolor(self):
    return json.loads(self.scolor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал 3 choices c null=True. Скрыл эти поля, теперь если 1 цвет,  остальные вернут пустое значение. Не идеально, но тоже решение... просто если поле пустое, оно не будет отображается. Но, к сожалению,  в бд оно будет,  что не добавляет скорости и памяти... когда будут 100500 таких данных. Но это уже другая история))
Спасибо большое за соучастие!!! Без вас как без рук)))